# Deploying Firestore Rules in a CI/CD Process (Scripted without the CLI)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, continuous-deployment

Looking at the doc pages for Firestore security rules, I am seeing that they're [deployable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) via the CLI.

I am wondering if anyone knows a way to deploy the contents of the `.rules` file without using the CLI.

I dug around and found this [firebase rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/app-management) REST API but that turned out to be a very different thing.

Short of studying their CLI code and writing some script to import their functions, does anyone know of a lib or already have code to do this?

I would like to be able to deploy these rules as part of the app deploy on an AWS CodePipeline, so the CLI is just not a good fit here.  Shelling out is not preferable either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase admin sdk in your ci pipeline to deploy rules for firestore/storage/RTDB. Below is an example snippet from [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy#use_the_admin_sdk)

```
  const source = `service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /carts/{cartID} {
          allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.ownerUID;
          allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerUID;
        }
      }
  }`;

// Alternatively, load rules from a file
// const fs = require('fs');
// const source = fs.readFileSync('path/to/firestore.rules', 'utf8');

await admin.securityRules().releaseFirestoreRulesetFromSource(source);
```